# Error starting ClamAV daemon

Tags: 14.04, server, clamav

I can't get the ClamAV daemon to start on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. Here's what I get when I try to start the service:

```
sudo service clamav-daemon start
* Starting ClamAV daemon clamd  [fail]
```

When I try to run the `clamdscan` here's what I get

```
clamdscan test.jpg
ERROR: Could not lookup (null): Servname not supported for ai_socktype

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 1
Time: 0.000 sec (0 m 0 s)
```

When I run the normal `clamscan` on the file, everything is fine:

```
clamscan test.jpg
test.jpg: OK

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 3708601
Engine version: 0.98.5
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 1
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.18 MB
Data read: 0.18 MB (ratio 1.02:1)
Time: 9.991 sec (0 m 9 s)
```

Here are the packages I have installed related to ClamAV:

```
> dpkg -l | grep 'clam'
ii  clamav                              0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1   amd64        anti-virus utility for Unix - command-line interface
ii  clamav-base                         0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1   all          anti-virus utility for Unix - base package
ii  clamav-daemon                       0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1   amd64        anti-virus utility for Unix - scanner daemon
ii  clamav-freshclam                    0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1   amd64        anti-virus utility for Unix - virus database update utility
ii  libclamav6                          0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1   amd64        anti-virus utility for Unix - library
```

Here are the contents of `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf` http://paste.ubuntu.com/9544920/

Here are the contents of `ll /var/run/` http://paste.ubuntu.com/9553966/

Comment: Please delete all of your coments as they have been incorporated into your question already...  ;)
Furthermore, post the output of :`ll /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl` (we're now going to go through the entire clamd config)  :(

Comment: Could you please add the output of `ll /var/run/` to your question in a few minutes?  I'll remove the redundant/unhelpful info first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was memory usage. Apparently `clamav-daemon` uses about 300MB of memory when all the virus libraries loaded. I'm running on a small VPS with 1GB of RAM and `mysql-server-5.6` takes up a big chunk of that. To improve performance I added `performance_schema = off` to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` which reduced memory consumption by about 400MB! (why is this the new default in 5.6.6?!). Anyway, that freed up some memory which allowed `clamav-daemon` to start without a problem.

Comment: Can't believe clamav-daemon doesn't throw some specific error for this issue! Thank god for your comment otherwise I would have wasted a lot more time trying to figure out the problem

Answer (score 4):

We've got it!  :-)
Type the following commands in a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo touch /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
sudo chown clamav:clamav /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
```

start `clamd` again!

Answer (score 3):

I have run into this issue pretty consistently when provisioning vagrant boxes with clamav.  Ensuring definitions have been downloaded and restarting the service consistently fixes it.

`sudo freshclam && sudo service clamav-daemon restart`

Comment: +1 thank you! I was provisioning a vagrant box and this was the solution that worked for me.

Comment: after messing with docker memory limits for a while, this was the fix