# ClamAV installation Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, clamav

I am trying to install ClamAV in ubuntu as per the instructions in:

- [blog.dutchcoders.io: Howto - Installing ClamAV from source](http://blog.dutchcoders.io/installing-clamav-from-source/)

While updating the virus databases using

```
 sudo freshclam -v
```

I am getting

Current working dir is /usr/local/share/clamav

```
Max retries == 3

ClamAV update process started at Mon Apr 11 13:10:34 2016

Using IPv6 aware code

Retrieving database.clamav.net/main.cvd

nonblock_connect: connect timing out (30 secs)

Can't connect to port 80 of host database.clamav.net (IP: 219.94.128.99)

Ignoring mirror 219.94.128.99 (due to previous errors)

Trying host database.clamav.net (27.96.54.66)...

nonblock_connect: connect timing out (30 secs)

Can't connect to port 80 of host database.clamav.net (IP: 27.96.54.66)

Trying host database.clamav.net (203.178.137.175)...

nonblock_connect: connect timing out (30 secs)

Can't connect to port 80 of host database.clamav.net (IP: 203.178.137.175)

Trying host database.clamav.net (211.239.150.206)...

nonblock_connect: connect timing out (30 secs)

Can't connect to port 80 of host database.clamav.net (IP: 211.239.150.206)

Trying host database.clamav.net (120.29.176.126)...

nonblock_connect: connect timing out (30 secs)

Can't connect to port 80 of host database.clamav.net (IP: 120.29.176.126)

WARNING: Can't download main.cvd from database.clamav.net

Trying again in 5 secs...

ClamAV update process started at Mon Apr 11 13:13:09 2016

Using IPv6 aware code

Retrieving database.clamav.net/main.cvd

Ignoring mirror 120.29.176.126 (due to previous errors)

Ignoring mirror 211.239.150.206 (due to previous errors)

Ignoring mirror 27.96.54.66 (due to previous errors)

Ignoring mirror 203.178.137.175 (due to previous errors)

Ignoring mirror 219.94.128.99 (due to previous errors)

WARNING: Can't download main.cvd from database.clamav.net

Trying again in 5 secs...

ClamAV update process started at Mon Apr 11 13:13:15 2016

Using IPv6 aware code

Retrieving database.clamav.net/main.cvd

Ignoring mirror 27.96.54.66 (due to previous errors)

Ignoring mirror 211.239.150.206 (due to previous errors)

Ignoring mirror 120.29.176.126 (due to previous errors)

Ignoring mirror 219.94.128.99 (due to previous errors)

Ignoring mirror 203.178.137.175 (due to previous errors)

ERROR: Can't download main.cvd from database.clamav.net

Giving up on database.clamav.net...

Update failed. Your network may be down or none of the mirrors listed in  /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf is working. Check http://www.clamav.net/doc/mirrors-faq.html for possible reasons.
```

Why is it so?? Is there any other way to resolve it??

I dont want ClamTK.

The outcome of mirrors.dat file is

```
Mirror #1
IP: 120.29.176.126
Successes: 0
Failures: 1
Last access: Mon Apr 11 12:37:04 2016
Ignore: Yes
-------------------------------------
>Mirror #2
IP: 203.178.137.175
Successes: 0
Failures: 1
Last access: Mon Apr 11 12:37:04 2016
Ignore: Yes
-------------------------------------
Mirror #3
IP: 27.96.54.66
Successes: 0
Failures: 1
Last access: Mon Apr 11 12:37:04 2016
Ignore: Yes
-------------------------------------
Mirror #4
IP: 211.239.150.206
Successes: 0
Failures: 1
Last access: Mon Apr 11 12:37:04 2016
Ignore: Yes
-------------------------------------
Mirror #5
IP: 219.94.128.99
Successes: 0
Failures: 1
Last access: Mon Apr 11 12:37:04 2016
Ignore: Yes
```

Contents of freshclam.conf file is,

```
##
## Example config file for freshclam
## Please read the freshclam.conf(5) manual before editing this file.
##


# Comment or remove the line below.
#Example

# Path to the database directory.
# WARNING: It must match clamd.conf's directive!
# Default: hardcoded (depends on installation options)
#DatabaseDirectory /var/lib/clamav

# Path to the log file (make sure it has proper permissions)
# Default: disabled
#UpdateLogFile /var/log/freshclam.log

# Maximum size of the log file.
# Value of 0 disables the limit.
# You may use 'M' or 'm' for megabytes (1M = 1m = 1048576 bytes)
# and 'K' or 'k' for kilobytes (1K = 1k = 1024 bytes).
# in bytes just don't use modifiers. If LogFileMaxSize is enabled,
# log rotation (the LogRotate option) will always be enabled.
# Default: 1M
#LogFileMaxSize 2M

# Log time with each message.
# Default: no
#LogTime yes

# Enable verbose logging.
# Default: no
#LogVerbose yes

# Use system logger (can work together with UpdateLogFile).
# Default: no
#LogSyslog yes

# Specify the type of syslog messages - please refer to 'man syslog'
# for facility names.
# Default: LOG_LOCAL6
#LogFacility LOG_MAIL

# Enable log rotation. Always enabled when LogFileMaxSize is enabled.
# Default: no
#LogRotate yes

# This option allows you to save the process identifier of the daemon
# Default: disabled
#PidFile /var/run/freshclam.pid

# By default when started freshclam drops privileges and switches to the
# "clamav" user. This directive allows you to change the database owner.
# Default: clamav (may depend on installation options)
#DatabaseOwner clamav

# Initialize supplementary group access (freshclam must be started by root).
# Default: no
#AllowSupplementaryGroups yes

# Use DNS to verify virus database version. Freshclam uses DNS TXT records
# to verify database and software versions. With this directive you can change
# the database verification domain.
# WARNING: Do not touch it unless you're configuring freshclam to use your
# own database verification domain.
# Default: current.cvd.clamav.net
#DNSDatabaseInfo current.cvd.clamav.net

# Uncomment the following line and replace XY with your country
# code. See www.iana.org/cctld/cctld-whois.htm for the full list.
# You can use db.XY.ipv6.clamav.net for IPv6 connections.
#DatabaseMirror db.XY.clamav.net

# database.clamav.net is a round-robin record which points to our most 
# reliable mirrors. It's used as a fall back in case db.XY.clamav.net is 
# not working. DO NOT TOUCH the following line unless you know what you
# are doing.
DatabaseMirror database.clamav.net

# How many attempts to make before giving up.
# Default: 3 (per mirror)
#MaxAttempts 5

# With this option you can control scripted updates. It's highly recommended
# to keep it enabled.
# Default: yes
#ScriptedUpdates yes

# By default freshclam will keep the local databases (.cld) uncompressed to
# make their handling faster. With this option you can enable the compression;
# the change will take effect with the next database update.
# Default: no
#CompressLocalDatabase no

# With this option you can provide custom sources for
# database files. This option can be used multiple times.
# Default: no custom URLs
#DatabaseCustomURL myserver.com/mysigs.ndb
#DatabaseCustomURL mnt/nfs/local.hdb

# This option allows you to easily point freshclam to private mirrors.
# If PrivateMirror is set, freshclam does not attempt to use DNS
# to determine whether its databases are out-of-date, instead it will
# use the If-Modified-Since request or directly check the headers of the
# remote database files. For each database, freshclam first attempts
# to download the CLD file. If that fails, it tries to download the
# CVD file. This option overrides DatabaseMirror, DNSDatabaseInfo
# and ScriptedUpdates. It can be used multiple times to provide
# fall-back mirrors.
# Default: disabled
#PrivateMirror mirror1.mynetwork.com
#PrivateMirror mirror2.mynetwork.com

# Number of database checks per day.
# Default: 12 (every two hours)
#Checks 24

# Proxy settings
# Default: disabled
#HTTPProxyServer myproxy.com
#HTTPProxyPort 1234
#HTTPProxyUsername myusername
#HTTPProxyPassword mypass

# If your servers are behind a firewall/proxy which applies User-Agent
# filtering you can use this option to force the use of a different
# User-Agent header.
# Default: clamav/version_number
#HTTPUserAgent SomeUserAgentIdString

# Use aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd as client address for downloading databases. Useful for
# multi-homed systems.
# Default: Use OS'es default outgoing IP address.
#LocalIPAddress aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd

# Send the RELOAD command to clamd.
# Default: no
#NotifyClamd /path/to/clamd.conf

# Run command after successful database update.
# Default: disabled
#OnUpdateExecute command

# Run command when database update process fails.
# Default: disabled
#OnErrorExecute command

# Run command when freshclam reports outdated version.
# In the command string %v will be replaced by the new version number.
# Default: disabled
#OnOutdatedExecute command

# Don't fork into background.
# Default: no
#Foreground yes

# Enable debug messages in libclamav.
# Default: no
#Debug yes

# Timeout in seconds when connecting to database server.
# Default: 30
#ConnectTimeout 60

# Timeout in seconds when reading from database server.
# Default: 30
#ReceiveTimeout 60

# With this option enabled, freshclam will attempt to load new
# databases into memory to make sure they are properly handled
# by libclamav before replacing the old ones.
# Default: yes
#TestDatabases yes

# When enabled freshclam will submit statistics to the ClamAV Project about
# the latest virus detections in your environment. The ClamAV maintainers
# will then use this data to determine what types of malware are the most
# detected in the field and in what geographic area they are.
# Freshclam will connect to clamd in order to get recent statistics.
# Default: no
#SubmitDetectionStats /path/to/clamd.conf

# Country of origin of malware/detection statistics (for statistical
# purposes only). The statistics collector at ClamAV.net will look up
# your IP address to determine the geographical origin of the malware
# reported by your installation. If this installation is mainly used to
# scan data which comes from a different location, please enable this
# option and enter a two-letter code (see www.iana.org/domains/root/db/)
# of the country of origin.
# Default: disabled
#DetectionStatsCountry country-code

# This option enables support for our "Personal Statistics" service. 
# When this option is enabled, the information on malware detected by
# your clamd installation is made available to you through our website.
# To get your HostID, log on http://www.stats.clamav.net and add a new
# host to your host list. Once you have the HostID, uncomment this option
# and paste the HostID here. As soon as your freshclam starts submitting
# information to our stats collecting service, you will be able to view
# the statistics of this clamd installation by logging into
# www.stats.clamav.net with the same credentials you used to
# generate the HostID. For more information refer to:
# www.clamav.net/documentation.html#cctts 
# This feature requires SubmitDetectionStats to be enabled.
# Default: disabled
#DetectionStatsHostID unique-id

# This option enables support for Google Safe Browsing. When activated for
# the first time, freshclam will download a new database file (safebrowsing.cvd)
# which will be automatically loaded by clamd and clamscan during the next
# reload, provided that the heuristic phishing detection is turned on. This
# database includes information about websites that may be phishing sites or
# possible sources of malware. When using this option, it's mandatory to run
# freshclam at least every 30 minutes.
# Freshclam uses the ClamAV's mirror infrastructure to distribute the
# database and its updates but all the contents are provided under Google's
# terms of use. See www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing
# and www.clamav.net/documentation.html#safebrowsing 
# for more information.
# Default: disabled
#SafeBrowsing yes

# This option enables downloading of bytecode.cvd, which includes additional
# detection mechanisms and improvements to the ClamAV engine.
# Default: enabled
#Bytecode yes

# Download an additional 3rd party signature database distributed through
# the ClamAV mirrors. 
# This option can be used multiple times.
#ExtraDatabase dbname1
#ExtraDatabase dbname2
```

Moreover if try to run the command

```
/usr/local/bin/freshclam --quiet -l         /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
```

it is showing

```
ERROR: Can't download main.cvd from database.clamav.net
```

Comment: From ur logs it shows that clamav is trying to get the updates from the nearest servers when one fails it tries the other. Try few times after a while and see it does the updates.

Comment: i am trying for more than 2 days

Comment: did u check the `freshclam.conf` file? Can u put the output of the file?

Comment: also put the output from `/usr/local/share/clamav/mirrors.dat` file

Comment: updated the post with freshclam.conf and mirrors.dat files

Comment: from ur config find this `WARNING: Do not touch it unless you're configuring freshclam to use your` and try to add ur country code there.U can check ur country code from here http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db .After that try it.

Comment: Replace XY with ur country code in this two lines `You can use db.XY.ipv6.clamav.net for IPv6 connections.`
 `DatabaseMirror db.XY.clamav.net`   such as us/uk/fi/

Comment: Replaced XY with country code. But still ERROR: Can't download main.cvd from db.in.clamav.net

Comment: can u try with jp or us. It seems like it does get the sync.

Comment: WARNING: Can't download main.cvd from db.jp.clamav.net WARNING: Can't download main.cvd from db.us.clamav.net

Comment: This is very strange. What do u see in `tail /var/log/clamav/freshclam` ? `freshclam --on-outdated-execute=COMMAND` . and try to get the recommended version.

Comment: But when i try to identify the version of daemon using "clamdscan -V ", it is showing "ERROR: Could not lookup : Servname not supported for ai_socktype" I installed from source clamav 0.99.1. It is working for clamscan -V but not for clamdscan -V

Comment: did u upgrade clamav  ? I am glad it finally worked for you.

Comment: upgrading is using sudo freshclam right?? i did it

Comment: shall I put it as an answer so that it helps others?

Comment: yeah sure.. but i need daemon too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In `freshclam.conf` file find the line

   ```
   #DatabaseMirror db.XY.clamav.net
   ```

   and uncomment it.

   - for IPv4:

     ```
     DatabaseMirror db.us.clamav.net
     ```
   - for IPv6 add this line too in your conf file

     ```
     DatabaseMirror db.us.ipv6.clamav.net
     ```

   Replace `XY` with your country code such as `fi|in|us|jp`
2. Save the file and run from terminal

   ```
   sudo freshclam -v
   ```

Now you should be able to do the update to freshclam database.

Comment: can u help with that daemon?

Comment: tell me more here?

Comment: I am getting "ERROR: Could not lookup : Servname not supported for ai_socktype" when i use command "sudo clamdscan -v" i referred to "http://askubuntu.com/questions/561842/error-starting-clamav-daemon" but still no hope

Comment: did you try the suggested solution from that question?

Comment: ya i tried all the three solutions

Comment: did u verify that you have all the required packages?

Comment: when i run the command "dpkg -l | grep 'clam' ".. i m getting "clamav-base, clamav-daemon, clamav-freshclam, libclamav6"

Comment: I would suggest you to put a new question and refer to that question that you followed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing using apt-get tool;

```
apt-get update # apt-get install clamav
```

link: https://www.clamav.net/documents/installing-clamav#debian

Comment: But i want to install from source.  Even if i install via apt-get, when i run the command sudo freshclam -v  i am getting the same problem

Comment: Reading the Mirror error your getting the FAQ recommends stopping the freshclam daemon then delete both mirrors.dat and daily.cvd. Then restart the freshclam daemon and its should re-download daily.cvd. [FAQ LINK](http://www.clamav.net/documents/official-mirror-faq)

Comment: I stopped to freshclam using "sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam stop". Then only mirrors.dat is there under "/usr/local/share/clamav/". I removed that. Then started freshclam using "sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam start". After this if i run "sudo freshclam -v" it is showing the same problem