# ClamAV Daemon ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, clamav

I am trying to install ClamAV in ubuntu as per the instructions in

> blog.dutchcoders.io/installing-clamav-from-source/

Everything worked perfectly except last step i.e.,

> clamd &

When i run the above command it is showing

> ERROR: Please define server type (local and/or TCP).

When i used the command

> sudo clamdscan -v

I got the output as

> ERROR: Could not lookup : Servname not supported for ai_socktype
>
> ----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
>
> Infected files: 0
>
> Total errors: 1
>
> Time: 0.000 sec (0 m 0 s)

I followed all the solutions in [Error starting ClamAV daemon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561842/error-starting-clamav-daemon) But no hope. Is there any other way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

By editing clamd.conf as below, the problem solves

```
# Log additional information about the infected file, such as its
# size and hash, together with the virus name.
#ExtendedDetectionInfo yes

# This option allows you to save a process identifier of the listening
# daemon (main thread).
# Default: disabled
PidFile /var/run/clamd.pid

# Optional path to the global temporary directory.
# Default: system specific (usually /tmp or /var/tmp).
TemporaryDirectory /var/tmp

# Path to the database directory.
# Default: hardcoded (depends on installation options)
DatabaseDirectory /usr/local/share/clamav

# Only load the official signatures published by the ClamAV project.
# Default: no
#OfficialDatabaseOnly no

# The daemon can work in local mode, network mode or both. 
# Due to security reasons we recommend the local mode.

# Path to a local socket file the daemon will listen on.
# Default: disabled (must be specified by a user)
LocalSocket /tmp/clamd.socket
```

Now if i enter 'clamd &' it is showing

> [3] 12859

Then 'sudo service clamav-daemon start' shows

> [3]   Done                    clamd

Then 'clamdscan -v' shows

> /usr/local/etc: OK
>
> ----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
> Infected files: 0
> Time: 0.017 sec (0 m 0 s)

Then 'clamdscan -V' shows

> ClamAV 0.99.1/21490/Tue Apr 12 08:04:23 2016